# Keep getting "No space left on device or exceeds fs.inotify.max_user_watches" despite setting a watch count to a higher value

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, sysctl

I'm trying to a run a `bitbake` command to build an image but I see the following errors

```
ERROR: No space left on device or exceeds fs.inotify.max_user_watches?
ERROR: To check max_user_watches: sysctl -n fs.inotify.max_user_watches.
ERROR: To modify max_user_watches: sysctl -n -w fs.inotify.max_user_watches=<value>.
ERROR: Root privilege is required to modify max_user_watches.
```

Ran a script to determine what process is has however many watch count and I get the following:

```
   INOTIFY
   WATCHER
    COUNT     PID     CMD
----------------------------------------
   11978    15732  /snap/sublime-text/97/opt/sublime_text/plugin_host 15717 --auto-shell-env
   11978    15717  /snap/sublime-text/97/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text
      51    10165  /usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon/unity-settings-daemon
      12     1759  /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-trash --spawner :1.6 /org/gtk/gvfs/exec_spaw/0
...
```

Running the following command returns the max watch count set which is greater than `11978` and I'm still seeing the same error.

```
$ sysctl -n fs.inotify.max_user_watches
12288
```

Is there anything else I should be looking into?

Comment: Can you also check inode use, `df -hi`

Comment: or you mean `df -h .`? there's enough space in the disk

Comment: Well, checking disk space is step one - checking inodes is step two (hence the -i). So yes, run the command I suggested 

Answer (score 3):

If you use VS Code Remote-SSH this error will come
to prevent this error, only one option close VS Code or try to exclude large folders from file watcher with the files.watcherExclude setting.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_visual-studio-code-is-unable-to-watch-for-file-changes-in-this-large-workspace-error-enospc

Comment: Upvoting because this is pretty much the only hit on Google for this error, and it helped me out.

Answer (score 3):

The solution in the link below fixed this issue for me:

https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/error-no-space-left-on-device.27809/post-141252

In summary:

Check the current limit:
`cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`

For me this was 64000

Temporarily test if increasing the value fixes things: (this will reset to the default of 8192 next reboot)
`echo 1048576 > /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`

Keep in mind at the size of ~1k each, this will increase the RAM consumption by watches from ~8MB to ~1GB. You may not need it to be this large. Try something smaller to conserve RAM.

If the above makes the problem go away, we can now make it permanent through reboots:
Edit /etc/sysctl.conf

`nano /etc/sysctl.conf`

Add the following line (or edit it if present already)
`fs.inotify.max_user_watches=128000`

Edit the 128000 value to suit your needs as discussed above

Reboot, or do the following:
`sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/436597)